# Visual Studio 2010 Build server with VS 2013 Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild

I was wondering if it was possible to build (in release) a 2013 visual studio solution file within Visual Studio 2010.

Search engine is coming up with 2010 to 2013 related issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will probable need SP1 for Visual Studio 2010. Even then you need to refer to the [Visual Studio 2013 compatibility page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx) to determine if the scenario you are looking for is supported. It will depend on the exact type of project you are building, the version of framework you are using, templates you are using, etc.